# What does an 'organic' letter mean?

Tags: terminology, latin

> [simultaneous (adj.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=simultaneous&searchmode=none) [:]
>       1650s, from Medieval Latin simultaneus, perhaps from simultim "at the same time," extended from Latin simul "at the same time" (see similar (adj.)), or from simul with ending abstracted from Late Latin spontaneus, where **the -*t*- is organic**. [...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that in *spontaneus* the **t** belongs to the root of the word, it's an organic, natural part of that word, while in *simultaneus* the **t** and the whole ending *-taneous* was abstracted from *spontaneus* and added to the word *simul* 'together'.

Comment: Note that talking about "letters" is a category error. The whole discussion is about sounds.

Comment: In this case, phonemes that are part of morpheme stems, or not. So the root is _spont-_ (ending in /t/) in one case, but _simul-_ in the other.